# How to customize feedback page Dspace XMLUI?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, user-experience, dspace

How to customize or change the contact page of dspace 5.5 XMLUI? What files or configuration should I change?

Comment: Have you read the [XMLUI Configuration and Customization documentation](https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC5x/XMLUI+Configuration+and+Customization)?

Comment: @JonnyHenly is there anything on Contact and Feedback on this https://wiki.lyrasis.org/display/DSDOC5x/Mirage+Configuration+and+Customization page?

Answer (score 1):

To add additional content to the page you have two options:

One option is to customize [Contact.addBody](https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/dspace-5.5/dspace-xmlui/src/main/java/org/dspace/app/xmlui/aspect/artifactbrowser/Contact.java#L92). For example:

```
public void addBody(Body body) throws ... {
    [...]
    contact.addPara("For urgent matters call 555-666-777.");
}
```

Use the IDE autocompletion to see what kind of elements you can add. There are equivalents to the basic HTML elements. See [DRI Schema Reference](https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC5x/DRI+Schema+Reference) to understand it better.

The other option is to add the content through an XSL file:

First, create `dspace-xmlui-mirage2/src/main/webapp/xsl/aspect/artifactbrowser/contact.xsl` (assuming Mirage 2 theme) with the following content:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:i18n="http://apache.org/cocoon/i18n/2.1"
    xmlns:dri="http://di.tamu.edu/DRI/1.0/"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    exclude-result-prefixes="i18n dri xsl">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="dri:div[@id='aspect.artifactbrowser.Contact.div.contact']">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
        <!-- Add here any additional HTML: -->
        <p>
        For urgent matters call 555-666-777.
        </p>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Then, add a reference at the end of `dspace-xmlui-mirage2/src/main/webapp/xsl/theme.xsl`:

```
<xsl:import href="aspect/artifactbrowser/contact.xsl"/>
```

Comment: I just want to add some more information on the contact page.

Comment: What is the file path to do this in Mirage Theme?